# "migration directory does not exist" error when running Yii-user extension's migrations

Tags: php, yii, composer-php, yii-extensions, yii-migrations

I have a Yii framework installed by Composer, webapp in public_html folder and all libraries in vendor folder:

```
webroot
|
|_public_html
|
|_vendor
  |
  |_fierwebdesign
    |
    |_yii-user
      |
      |_migrations
```

My configuration in `console.php` is:

```
'modules'=>array(
  'user'=>array(
     'hash' => 'md5',
      'sendActivationMail' => true,
      'loginNotActiv' => false,
      'activeAfterRegister' => false,
      'autoLogin' => true,
      'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),
      'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),
      'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
      'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),
      'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),
    ),
),
```

When I try to run Yii-user extension's migrations, I'm getting error:

```
yiic.php migrate --migrationPath=vendor.fierwebdesign.yii-user.migrations

Error: The migration directory does not exist: vendor.fierwebdesign.yii-user.migrations
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need declare `vendor` alias in configs. If your console.php in `public_html/config/` than declaration is:

> ```
> Yii::setPathOfAlias('vendor', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' .
>                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '_vendor');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

write something like this within the `components` array in the `console.php` config file;

```
    'commandMap' => array(
        'migrate' => array(
            'class' => 'system.cli.commands.MigrateCommand',
            'migrationPath' => 'application.modules.user.migrations',
//            'migrationTable' => 'tbl_migration',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
//            'templateFile' => 'application.migrations.template',
        ),
```

and then give the command : `php migrate`

also, the `app/modules/user/migartion` folder must exist in this case and must contain migratio files

Comment: No. Because Yii-user module not in folder modules.user. Yii-User installed in vendor.fierwebdesign.yii-user.migrations. If i write this with my path:  Error: The migration directory does not exist: vendor.fierwebdesign.yii-user.migrations

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that `migrationPath` actually refers to a file system path instead of to an alias like you are using